# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

I am trying to build a *login/signup* system on my **React** website using **JWT**.

I have an API set up which works perfectly. I need to integrate the user login flow with the server.

This is my `userSlice` -

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    signup: (state, action) => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          state.user = res.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    login: (state, action) => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      }).then((res) => {
        state.user = res.data;
      });
    },
    logout: (state) => {},
  },
});

export const { login, logout, signup } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**`Signup` Component** -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { signup } from "../../features/userSlice";

import "./Signup.css";

function Signup() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const signUpHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(signup(name, email, password));
  };

  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>
      <form method="POST">
        <div className="input_area">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="input_area">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div className="input_area">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <button onClick={signUpHandler} type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

When I click the Sign Up button, I get this error -

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked**

Any idea what's causing the error? The backend works fine.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

There was a mistake on my part after fetch. Instead of `state.user = res.data`  I had to do `state.user = JSON.parse(res.data)`

But after I do this, I get a different error which says -

*Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0*

**This is the response I get in POSTMAN**

[image: This is the response I get in POSTMAN]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use `https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk` instead since you're calling an api here.

Comment: please check the edit, I rectified an error and I get another

Comment: The error `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` means res.data is not a JSON string.

Comment: yea i saw that in the Networks tab in Chrome. Why is that so? What's causing the issue?

Comment: Your API is not returning JSON. You didn't provide the code and you mentioned that it works fine. I'm not sure how to help with that.

Comment: You mean the API?

Comment: I added a snapshot of the response